# Most recommended CSS Media Query for Mobile Phones and Tablet Devices

Tags: css, media-queries

I wanted some insight on what could be the most recommended css media query to target mobile phones (handheld) and tablets. I have the following code and I wanted to know if it

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (min-device-width : 768px) {
    /*style*/
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This Will be helpfull...

```
 @media (min-width:320px)  { /* smartphones, portrait iPhone, portrait 480x320 phones (Android) */ }
    @media (min-width:480px)  { /* smartphones, Android phones, landscape iPhone */ }
    @media (min-width:600px)  { /* portrait tablets, portrait iPad, e-readers (Nook/Kindle), landscape 800x480 phones (Android) */ }
    @media (min-width:801px)  { /* tablet, landscape iPad, lo-res laptops ands desktops */ }
    @media (min-width:1025px) { /* big landscape tablets, laptops, and desktops */ }
    @media (min-width:1281px) { /* hi-res laptops and desktops */ }
```

Comment: Ah, yes. That's what I was looking for! Thank you.